# Worklight 6.2: Unable to build iOS app using build machines

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Environment:

- Worklight 6.2,
- Dojo 1.9.4,
- Cordova 3.4.1

We have created a hybrid app using Worklight 6.1.0.2 and now we have updated the Worklight to 6.2.0.1. After that I have deleted and recreated the iPad environment. We have also updated the worklight version to 6.2.0.1 in our build machines. But when we try to build the iOS app using worklight on the build machine, if gives following error -

> ld: file not found:
>   /build/root/RQMOffline/RQMOffline6.0.1-T20151012_1707/QMMobile/apps/MobileAppName/ipad/native/build/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

We would like to know, how we can fix this issue.
Please let me know, if more details are required.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: The exception is incomplete. Provide the full exception as well as mention the **build number** of your 6.2.0.1 installation.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the latest available 6.2.0.1 iFix (6.2.0.01-20151008-1615), created a new project -> application -> iPad, built and opened in Xcode 7 and ran in the iOS Simulator. The build passed successfully and the application launched in the simulator.

You are unclear on what is actually happening in your project. i.e, are you using the nativeResources folder to copy over stored files? You also did not provide the full exception from Xcode.

Comment: I guess, there is some issue with "project.pbxproj" file. When we change the path in the build settings to - "\"$(SRCROOT)/CordovaLib/build/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/libCordova.a\""
from - "\"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a\"" now there is no linker error for libCordova.a file.
Now the problem is with the sqlcipher file. The "sqlcipher" file is not found while building the iOS app.